# testing angular app using karma and jasmine having error:

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner

I am new to angular.js. I am trying to run Karma unit tests for my application but have found a lot of problems as it expects I install all required dependencies like node.js, npm, karma etc.

Now when i goto the my project directory and run this command karma start karma i have this error:

```
C:\wamp\www\First-angular-App>karma start karma.conf
ERROR [config]: Invalid config file!
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

karma.conf

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({ 
    basePath: '', 
    frameworks: ['jasmine'], 
    exclude: [ ], 
    files: [ 'First-angular-App/source/index.html', 'First-angular-App/source/myApp.js' 'First-angular-App/source/myAppCtrl.js' ] 
    preprocessor 
    preprocessors: { }, 
    reporters: ['progress'], 
    port: 9876, 
    colors: true, 
    config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG 
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO, 
    changes 
    autoWatch: false, 
    launcher browsers: ['Chrome'], 
    singleRun: true 
  });
};
```

Why its giving me the error invalid config file ?

Comment: You running "karma start" and getting error "Invalid config file". Don't know what are you not understanding, but error says "My dear indian friend! you have something wrong in your configuration setting! please check that everything you got there exist, having right path to your npm libraries and many-many more reasons..."  Upload your karma.conf.js, I am not cthulhu to suggest you something.

Comment: @Dmitri if don't understand my problem why writing stories just do nothing its fine do your on work

Comment: @NumanHassan @Dimitri has no problem with understanding your problem. Please upload `config file` as you get `ERROR [config]: Invalid config file!`

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski here is my karma.conf module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({
basePath: '',
frameworks: ['jasmine'],
exclude: [
],
files: [ 
'First-angular-App/source/index.html',
'First-angular-App/source/myApp.js'
'First-angular-App/source/myAppCtrl.js'
]
preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},
reporters: ['progress'],
port: 9876,
colors: true,
config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
changes
autoWatch: false,
launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],
singleRun: true
});
};

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski i do that which you suggest but still same error i receive

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski i comment out this still same error // config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski still not resolve still saying invalid and giving  error

Comment: @NumanHassan few more missing commas when you listing files

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski in 2nd last statement launcher browser its ok or it should be only browser?

Comment: @NumanHassan Only `browsers` as key - I changed 5 hours ago the content of answer. Should be OK

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski now i receive warn messages can not load chrome it is not registered perhaps you are missing some plugins and also all files i included does not match any file these warn messages i received after running karma.conf

Comment: @NumanHassan have you miss to install https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it should looks like - please take a look for two comments added to configuration.

```
 module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        exclude: [ ],
        files: [ 'First-angular-App/source/index.html', 'First-angular-App/source/myApp.js', 'First-angular-App/source/myAppCtrl.js' ],
        // preprocessor - mark this as comment
        preprocessors: { },
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        // config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG - one more comment
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        // changes - mark this as comment
        autoWatch: false,
        // launcher 
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

Comment: i do that which is you mention above but still same error i receive

Comment: it still giving some error regarding file path that file does not match any file although karma is running

Comment: @NumanHassan Don't you know what are the file names and where you store it? Have you ever try to read some documentation like http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/intro/configuration.html ?